# Table of content for Dictionary

Tags: table-of-contents

I have one problem in the latex `\tableofcontents`.

Look at the image I circled.

```
For Dictionary from A-Z               1-250
```

How to do that in latex in `\tableofcontents`?

Is it possible in LaTeX?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the command `\addtocontents{toc}{STUFF}` adds anything you want to the table of contents.  You need to format your entry yourself, however.

If you look into TOC of a LaTeX file, you see that its entries have the following structure
`\contentsline {SECTION}{\numberline {NUMBER}TITLE}{PAGE}{HYPERLINK NAME}` (the last argument is there only if you use hyperref).  So you need to:

1. Put `\label{first_page}` on the first page.
2. Put `\label{last_page}` on the last page
3. Put on the first page `\addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline
   {section}{\numberline{} Words}{\pageref{first_page}--\pageref{last_page}}{}}`

You many need to change `section` to `chapter` here depending on the style you want.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Your information are really spare. The modification based also on the packages which creates the index. For example you can use `makeidx`, `scrindex` or `splitidx` ...

In my example I uses the class `scrbook` in combination with `scrindex`:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,idxtotoc]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{scrindex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[user,abspage]{zref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\idx@heading}{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
  \twocolumn[\idx@@heading{\indexname}]%
  \@mkboth{\indexname}{\indexname}%
}
\renewcommand*\idx@@heading[1]{%
   \phantomsection
   \chapter*{\hypertarget{indexlink}{#1}}\zlabel{startindex}
   \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{\@chapterlistsgap}}
   \addtocontents{toc}{%
            {\usekomafont{chapterentry}%
             \protect\hyperlink{indexlink}{\indexname}%
             \protect\hfill%
             \zpageref{startindex} -- \zpageref{endindex}%
            }}
}
\AtEndEnvironment{theindex}{\zlabel{endindex}}
\makeindex
\begin{document} 
\tableofcontents
\chapter{foo}
Text\index{Text}
\printindex
Test
\end{document}
```